# Split file with pattern and files name

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file contents with specific pattern, I would like to split that file into multiple files after pattern match with pattern name as a output file name. 
Examples

```
P1_1r6r

NRVSTVQQLTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINV LRGFRKEIG-    RMLNILNRRRRRVSTVQQLTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIP

P1_1sfk

MALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINVLRGFRKEIGRMLNILNRRRRRVSTVQQ LTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINVLRGFRKEI

P1_12562 RFSLPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINVLRGFRKEIGRM LNILNRRRRRVSTVQQLTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTI
```

So, here pattern is `P1`, I want to split the above file into 3 different files content with file name like `1r6r,1sfk,12562`.

Comment: is that right that the last line in your input has a crucial pattern and subsequent content on the same line `P1_12562 RFSLPLKL .....` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** approach:

```
awk '$1~/^P1_[0-9a-z]+/{ fn=substr($1,4); if(NF>1) { $1=""; print >> fn} next }
     NF && fn{ print >> fn }' file
```

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head 1*
==> 12562 <==
 RFSLPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINVLRGFRKEIGRM LNILNRRRRRVSTVQQLTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTI

==> 1r6r <==
NRVSTVQQLTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINV LRGFRKEIG-    RMLNILNRRRRRVSTVQQLTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIP

==> 1sfk <==
MALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINVLRGFRKEIGRMLNILNRRRRRVSTVQQ LTKRFSLGMLQGRGPLKLFMALVAFLRFLTIPPTAGILKRWGTIKKSKAINVLRGFRKEI
```

Comment: Command is executing well, But the problem is that, unable to print the file name like, 12562,1r6r and 1sfk in output file. So please modify once more in command. Thanks

Comment: @skumar, edit your question to show how should look the content of such one file